# How to install QuickFix/n

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, fix-protocol, quickfixn

Iam trying to install the QuickFix/n but i cannot figure out how to do it.

Even following the README doc and the http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/creating-an-application.html

When i include the library `using QuickFix;` inside the project it says that cannot be found

Comment: Please provide details on what you have tried and what errors you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the version you need from http://quickfixn.org/download/
2. Unpack ZIP and place `QuickFix.dll` somewhere (e.g. in your project folder)
3. In VS in your project's  Solution Explorer click "Add Reference..." click on "Browse" and find the stored on step 2. `QuickFix.dll`

Having the reference added, `using QuickFix;` and all instructions from Tutorial should work.